# Updating the name value in a TStringList name/value pair

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Is it possible to update the Name string of a particular TStringList name/value pair?

```
List.Names[I]:= name;
```

I know Names is a readonly property, I was wondering if there was another way that I don't know about?

Or do I have to do a entire update of the entire string

```
List[I]:= name=value
```

the problem is I store a large amount of string values in the value portion of the name/value pair

example

```
name=value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10
```

I would much rather just update the name portion 9cause that's all I need to do)

thanks

Comment: There is no "name portion"; the name and the value are stored together in a single string. Therefore, there is no penalty for modifying the entire item compared to modifying just the name portion since there's no way to do the latter anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need read the index of the item representing the name/value pair. Do that by calling `IndexOfName()`. And then you modify that item. So the code would look a little like this:

```
Index := List.IndexOfName(OldName);
if Index=-1 then
  // handle error
List[Index] := NewName + List.NameValueSeparator + List.ValueFromIndex[Index];
```

---

Since you are on a Delphi that has support for generics, you may be better off with `TDictionary<string, string>`.

Even then it's not trivial to change the name of an item. Translated to a dictionary the code looks like this:

```
Item := Dict.ExtractPair(OldName);
Dict.Add(NewName, Item.Value);
```

Comment: It was what I assumed, and already completed, but thanks for verifying that it was the only way